# Error: Minified React error #130, When rendering the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-extension, rollup

I am creating a chrome extension with react and an npm component package. I am trying to show an error message on the page. When I trigger the error message component, I am getting an error.

this is the error:-

`Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

But that error message component working normally in other codes. It only appears in my chrome extension.

This is my rollup config.!

```js
var babelPresets = [
    [ presetEnv, { modules: false } ],
    [ presetReact]
];
var babelPlugins = ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"];
 
modules.forEach((module, i) => {
        rollup({
            input: module.entry,
            treeshake: true,
            external:[],
            plugins: [
                postCss({
                    extract: true,
                    plugins: []
                }),
                commonjs({
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/**"),
                    namedExports: {
                        react: [
                            'PropTypes',
                            'createElement', 'Component', 'PureComponent', 'Fragment', 'createContext',
                            'forwardRef',
                            'useContext',
                            'useLayoutEffect',
                            'useEffect',
                            'useRef', "isValidElement", "useReducer", "useImperativeHandle",
                            'useState', 'useMemo', 'useCallback', "Children", "cloneElement", "createRef"
                        ],
                        "react-transition-group": ["CSSTransition"],
                        "react-dom": ["unmountComponentAtNode", "render"],
                        "react/jsx-runtime": ["jsxs", "jsx", "Fragment"]
                    }
                }),
                resolve({
                    mainFields: ["module", "main"],
                    customResolveOptions: {
                        moduleDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
                    }
                }),
                babel({
                    babelrc: false,
                    externalHelpers: false,
                    presets: babelPresets,
                    plugins: babelPlugins
                }),
                json(),
                replace({
                    "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
                })
            ]
        })
            .then( (bundle) => {
                bundle.write({
                    name: "__rollupModule",
                    format: "iife",
                    file: module.dest,
                    // footer: "window.__rollupModule = undefined;",
                    // dest: module.dest,
                    sourcemap: 'inline'
                }).then(() => {
                    if (i === modules.length - 1) {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => log(err));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

It seems like you have passed undefined as a component child/JXS node. Check what have you passed into the error message component using `console.log()`.

Comment: I have already checked that component, that does not have any problem. even I am using that same component in my other project, it works fine there..!

The error only occurs when I am using that in the chrome extension project.

Comment: @R.M.ARUNKUMAR Yeah the component itself can be perfectly fine, it's just that you passed some undefined data in there, which it's trying to show and ended up returning undefined within a JSX context, which caused the error. Look outside of your error component.